# Replace a content of a file using sed for a specific line in file which has two similar content

Tags: linux, sed

I need to provide `stdin` to this `sed` command mentioned below but after filtering. i.e I need to run this `sed` on a particular line of a text file.

```
sed -i "s/^nameserver \(.*\)/nameserver $sea/" conf
```

my `conf` file contains :

```
search
Nameserver 1
Nameserver 2
```

I need to make changes using `sed` to only second line of the file `conf`

Comment: use this `sed -i "2s/^nameserver \(.*\)/nameserver $sea/" conf` for `Nameserver 1`

Comment: use this `sed -i "3s/^nameserver \(.*\)/nameserver $sea/" conf` for `Nameserver 2`